# Does the subgroup index lowers when intersecting?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group, and suppose that $H$ is some finite index subgroup of $G$. Suppose furthermore that $Z \subset G$ is some central subgroup of $G$, which may be of infinite index.

1. Is it true that 
   $$
   |Z:Z \cap H| \le |G:H|
   $$
   ?
2. If 1 happens to be false, can we still say that $|Z:Z\cap H|$ is finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the composition of maps
$$Z \longrightarrow G \longrightarrow G/H$$
where the first is the inclusion, the second is the canonical projection.

Clearly the kernel is $Z \cap H$, so that $Z/(Z \cap H)$ can be embedded in $G/H$ by the first isomorphism theorem.

This means that $|Z:(Z \cap H)|$ divides $|G:H|$ (by Lagrange's theorem), and in particular it is smaller or equal.

Note that the hypothesis that $Z$ is central is not important.